# My VBA worksheet change coding hasn't been firing since I messed around with Application changes. help needed

Tags: excel, vba

I've been messing around with VBA coding and Macro's for the last couple of hours and I've encountered a problem. I read somewhere that you could optimise your code in some ways and tried them out on my project. Since then, I haven't been able to run any worksheet_change events since.

The addition consisted of two separate subs that I could call on before my own code ran and after it finished. These two subs looked like this:

```
Public CalcState As Long
Public EventState As Boolean
Public PageBreakState As Boolean

    Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    EventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    End Sub

Sub OptimizeCode_End()

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = EventState
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

My own code looked like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_change(byVal Target As Range)

Dim LastPopulatedRow As Long

Call OptimizeCode_Begin

LastPopulatedRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range.("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows

Sheets.("Sheet2").Range("C4:C" & LastPopulatedRow0.FillDown

Call Sub OptimizeCode-End

End Sub
```

I've looked everywhere on the internet for a potential fix but nothing seems to work. Can anybody help me out with this issue?

Comment: You need error handling so that `Application.EnableEvents` is always toggled back to `True`.

Comment: To start, put `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate Window and hit Enter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I entered Application.EnableEvents = True into my immediate window and when I put in ?Application.EnableEvents it also returns "True". But when I try run the code again it still doesn't respond.

Comment: Typo - `LastPopulatedRow0.FillDown` plus what's that `End` on the next line doing?

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change Issue

- I have removed the `PageBreaks` setting because it refers to a `Worksheet` while the others refer to the `Application` object.
- If `EnableEvents` is false then this code will not run anyway so why capture the state of `EnableEvents`. Just turn it off and when done turn it on again. The same for the other settings.
- BTW you are turning off `EnableEvents` to avoid an infinite loop.
- Copy the following into the sheet module e.g. `Sheet1`. Maybe run `turnOnSettings` first. Afterward, it should work on its own.

**Implement Error Handling and Simplify the 'Optimization'**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim LastPopulatedRow As Long
    LastPopulatedRow = sws.Range("B" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    turnOffSettings
    On Error GoTo SettingsError
    dws.Range("C4:C" & LastPopulatedRow).FillDown
    turnOnSettings

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

SettingsError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume Next ' Continue with 'turnOnSettings'

clearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit ' An error occurred before 'turnOffSettings'

End Sub

Sub turnOffSettings()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Sub turnOnSettings()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm this code doesn't seem to be working. I don't get any errors or anything but it just doesn't perform the described tasks. I think there could be an issue with VBA on my device itself. Is there any way to return VBA to its default state for Mac or is it hopeless?

Comment: I've improved my answer. Run `turnOnSettings` first and you should be good to go. Sorry but I don't know if there are any differences in Windows or in Mac concerning this issue.

Comment: Note that this event is only triggered if a value on the worksheet is changed manually, not by formula. Also, it is usually used for a smaller range than all the cells of the worksheet when the `Target` is tested if it intersects with the range, and only in that case, something is done (`Target` referring to the cell(s) changed).

Comment: For the most part it seemed to be running just fine but when I recieve a runtime error and now when I try to run the macro again it doesn't do anything. I've tried running the turnSettingsOn macro but this doesn't fix it.

Comment: This coding and the previous code seemed to work fine on another device but it just does't work on my own device. I'm going to try to restore my device to a previous backup to see if that fixes it. Thanks for the help anyway